# Is there a better alternative to Xpath to find elements for ReactJS apps?

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver, python-3.9

I'm really struggling trying to locate a specific element inside the HTML at the end of my question. I'm writing test scripts with Python and Selenium.

The element I'm looking for, is the following:

```html
<button class="jss906 jss1028" tabindex="0" type="button" aria-label="More" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="card-options-menu"><span class="jss1033"><svg class="jss169 jss170" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation"><path d="M12 8c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2s-.9-2-2-2-2 .9-2 2 .9 2 2 2zm0 2c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2s.9 2 2 2 2-.9 2-2-.9-2-2-2zm0 6c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2s.9 2 2 2 2-.9 2-2-.9-2-2-2z"></path></svg></span><span class="jss909"></span></button>
```

Related to the "Tester Fester" `<li>`. I've tried numerous methods (`find_element_by_xpath` has been my only really useful method as there are few if any distinguishable element id's or classes to search for). The app is written with MaterialUI and it's been a bit of a struggle locating elements all along (as noted) and I was wondering if anyone could hint at a strategy to find them (buttons mainly).

If I attempt a simple:
`driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[1]/div/main/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/ul/li[3]/ul/li[12]/div[2]/button')`

(XPATH copied directly from Chrome DevTools using right-click Inspect)

I get a `NoSuchElementException` because the page is not completely done loading.

If I instead write in a `driver.implicitly_wait(x)` for varying times, the script eventually just gets a `TimeoutException` and quits without finding the element at all...

Using `ExpectedConditions` like so:
`wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="root"]/div/div[1]/div/main/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/ul/li[3]/ul/li[12]/div[2]/button')))`

The same `TimeoutException` occurs.

```html
<li class="jss2662">
  <ul class="jss2663">
    <li class="jss2840 jss2845 jss2843">Active Team Members (12)</li>
    <li class="jss1724">
      <div class="jss1723 jss1726 jss1731 jss1733">
        <div theme="[object Object]" class="jss2740" style="position: relative; border: none; box-shadow: none; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; background: none;">
          <div class="jss1039" title=""><span class="jss1049"><span class="jss1050 jss1037 jss1054"></span></span>
          </div>
          <div class="jss1056 jss2740" theme="[object Object]"><img alt="AA" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/gather-app/image/upload/a_0,c_crop,h_447,r_0,w_447,x_131,y_0/c_limit,f_auto,q_auto,w_80/v1/qa/user_provided/entity/553/1609276302437-DNR8F6Q-Ox" class="jss1058"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="jss1745 jss2739"><span class="jss133 jss142 jss1748">Aaron Aaronson</span>
          <p class="jss133 jss141 jss166 jss1749">Invited by Aaron Aaronson</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="jss2846"><button class="jss906 jss1028" tabindex="0" type="button" aria-label="More" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="card-options-menu"><span class="jss1033"><svg class="jss169 jss170" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation"><path d="M12 8c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2s-.9-2-2-2-2 .9-2 2 .9 2 2 2zm0 2c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2s.9 2 2 2 2-.9 2-2-.9-2-2-2zm0 6c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2s.9 2 2 2 2-.9 2-2-.9-2-2-2z"></path></svg></span><span class="jss909"></span></button></div>
    </li>
    <li class="jss1724">
      <div class="jss1723 jss1726 jss1731 jss1733">
        <div theme="[object Object]" class="jss2740" style="position: relative; border: none; box-shadow: none; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; background: none;">
          <div class="jss1039" title=""><span class="jss1049"><span class="jss1050 jss1037 jss1054"></span></span>
          </div>
          <div class="jss1056 jss1057 jss2740" theme="[object Object]">CR</div>
        </div>
        <div class="jss1745 jss2739"><span class="jss133 jss142 jss1748">Cole Ross</span>
          <p class="jss133 jss141 jss166 jss1749">Invited by Aaron Aaronson</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="jss2846"><button class="jss906 jss1028" tabindex="0" type="button" aria-label="More" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="card-options-menu"><span class="jss1033"><svg class="jss169 jss170" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation"><path d="M12 8c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2s-.9-2-2-2-2 .9-2 2 .9 2 2 2zm0 2c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2s.9 2 2 2 2-.9 2-2-.9-2-2-2zm0 6c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2s.9 2 2 2 2-.9 2-2-.9-2-2-2z"></path></svg></span><span class="jss909"></span></button></div>
    </li>
    <li class="jss1724">
      <div class="jss1723 jss1726 jss1731 jss1733">
        <div theme="[object Object]" class="jss2740" style="position: relative; border: none; box-shadow: none; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; background: none;">
          <div class="jss1039" title=""><span class="jss1049"><span class="jss1050 jss1037 jss1054"></span></span>
          </div>
          <div class="jss1056 jss2740" theme="[object Object]"><img alt="GU" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/gather-app/image/upload/a_0,c_crop,h_690,r_0,w_690,x_105,y_0/c_limit,f_auto,q_auto,w_80/v1/qa/user_provided/user_profile/683/1601932158737-tENd4dRwex" class="jss1058"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="jss1745 jss2739"><span class="jss133 jss142 jss1748">Gath Us</span>
          <p class="jss133 jss141 jss166 jss1749">Invited by Aaron Aaronson</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="jss2846"><button class="jss906 jss1028" tabindex="0" type="button" aria-label="More" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="card-options-menu"><span class="jss1033"><svg class="jss169 jss170" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation"><path d="M12 8c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2s-.9-2-2-2-2 .9-2 2 .9 2 2 2zm0 2c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2s.9 2 2 2 2-.9 2-2-.9-2-2-2zm0 6c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2s.9 2 2 2 2-.9 2-2-.9-2-2-2z"></path></svg></span><span class="jss909"></span></button></div>
    </li>
    <li class="jss1724">
      <div class="jss1723 jss1726 jss1731 jss1733">
        <div theme="[object Object]" class="jss2740" style="position: relative; border: none; box-shadow: none; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; background: none;">
          <div class="jss1039" title=""><span class="jss1049"><span class="jss1050 jss1037 jss1054"></span></span>
          </div>
          <div class="jss1056 jss2740" theme="[object Object]"><img alt="GB" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/gather-app/image/upload/c_limit,f_auto,q_auto,w_80/v1/qa/user_provided/user_profile/7/gertrude" class="jss1058"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="jss1745 jss2739"><span class="jss133 jss142 jss1748">Gertrude Bjørnvig</span>
          <p class="jss133 jss141 jss166 jss1749">Invited by Aaron Aaronson</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="jss2846"><button class="jss906 jss1028" tabindex="0" type="button" aria-label="More" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="card-options-menu"><span class="jss1033"><svg class="jss169 jss170" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation"><path d="M12 8c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2s-.9-2-2-2-2 .9-2 2 .9 2 2 2zm0 2c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2s.9 2 2 2 2-.9 2-2-.9-2-2-2zm0 6c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2s.9 2 2 2 2-.9 2-2-.9-2-2-2z"></path></svg></span><span class="jss909"></span></button></div>
    </li>
    <li class="jss1724">
      <div class="jss1723 jss1726 jss1731 jss1733">
        <div theme="[object Object]" class="jss2740" style="position: relative; border: none; box-shadow: none; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; background: none;">
          <div class="jss1039" title=""><span class="jss1049"><span class="jss1050 jss1037 jss1054"></span></span>
          </div>
          <div class="jss1056 jss2740" theme="[object Object]"><img alt="gs" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/gather-app/image/upload/a_0,c_crop,h_90,r_0,w_90,x_193,y_329/c_limit,f_auto,q_auto,w_80/v1/qa/user_provided/user_profile/1215/1605874019679-2XlY6V0RKx" class="jss1058"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="jss1745 jss2739"><span class="jss133 jss142 jss1748">gom supa</span>
          <p class="jss133 jss141 jss166 jss1749">Invited by Aaron Aaronson</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="jss2846"><button class="jss906 jss1028" tabindex="0" type="button" aria-label="More" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="card-options-menu"><span class="jss1033"><svg class="jss169 jss170" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation"><path d="M12 8c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2s-.9-2-2-2-2 .9-2 2 .9 2 2 2zm0 2c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2s.9 2 2 2 2-.9 2-2-.9-2-2-2zm0 6c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2s.9 2 2 2 2-.9 2-2-.9-2-2-2z"></path></svg></span><span class="jss909"></span></button></div>
    </li>
    <li class="jss1724">
      <div class="jss1723 jss1726 jss1731 jss1733">
        <div theme="[object Object]" class="jss2740" style="position: relative; border: none; box-shadow: none; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; background: none;">
          <div class="jss1039" title=""><span class="jss1049"><span class="jss1050 jss1037 jss1054"></span></span>
          </div>
          <div class="jss1056 jss2740" theme="[object Object]"><img alt="hs" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/gather-app/image/upload/a_0,c_crop,h_832,r_max,w_832,x_0,y_233/c_limit,f_auto,q_auto,w_80/v1/qa/user_provided/user_profile/169/meq7v2a7p7wfrpckamih" class="jss1058"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="jss1745 jss2739"><span class="jss133 jss142 jss1748">harinder singh</span>
          <p class="jss133 jss141 jss166 jss1749">Invited by Aaron Aaronson</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="jss2846"><button class="jss906 jss1028" tabindex="0" type="button" aria-label="More" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="card-options-menu"><span class="jss1033"><svg class="jss169 jss170" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation"><path d="M12 8c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2s-.9-2-2-2-2 .9-2 2 .9 2 2 2zm0 2c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2s.9 2 2 2 2-.9 2-2-.9-2-2-2zm0 6c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2s.9 2 2 2 2-.9 2-2-.9-2-2-2z"></path></svg></span><span class="jss909"></span></button></div>
    </li>
    <li class="jss1724">
      <div class="jss1723 jss1726 jss1731 jss1733">
        <div theme="[object Object]" class="jss2740" style="position: relative; border: none; box-shadow: none; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; background: none;">
          <div class="jss1039" title=""><span class="jss1049"><span class="jss1050 jss1037 jss1054"></span></span>
          </div>
          <div class="jss1056 jss1057 jss2740" theme="[object Object]">jd</div>
        </div>
        <div class="jss1745 jss2739"><span class="jss133 jss142 jss1748">john doe</span>
          <p class="jss133 jss141 jss166 jss1749">Invited by Aaron Aaronson</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="jss2846"><button class="jss906 jss1028" tabindex="0" type="button" aria-label="More" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="card-options-menu"><span class="jss1033"><svg class="jss169 jss170" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation"><path d="M12 8c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2s-.9-2-2-2-2 .9-2 2 .9 2 2 2zm0 2c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2s.9 2 2 2 2-.9 2-2-.9-2-2-2zm0 6c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2s.9 2 2 2 2-.9 2-2-.9-2-2-2z"></path></svg></span><span class="jss909"></span></button></div>
    </li>
    <li class="jss1724">
      <div class="jss1723 jss1726 jss1731 jss1733">
        <div theme="[object Object]" class="jss2740" style="position: relative; border: none; box-shadow: none; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; background: none;">
          <div class="jss1039" title=""><span class="jss1049"><span class="jss1050 jss1037 jss1054"></span></span>
          </div>
          <div class="jss1056 jss1057 jss2740" theme="[object Object]">MF</div>
        </div>
        <div class="jss1745 jss2739"><span class="jss133 jss142 jss1748">McDonald Franchise</span>
          <p class="jss133 jss141 jss166 jss1749">Invited by john doe</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="jss2846"><button class="jss906 jss1028" tabindex="0" type="button" aria-label="More" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="card-options-menu"><span class="jss1033"><svg class="jss169 jss170" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation"><path d="M12 8c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2s-.9-2-2-2-2 .9-2 2 .9 2 2 2zm0 2c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2s.9 2 2 2 2-.9 2-2-.9-2-2-2zm0 6c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2s.9 2 2 2 2-.9 2-2-.9-2-2-2z"></path></svg></span><span class="jss909"></span></button></div>
    </li>
    <li class="jss1724">
      <div class="jss1723 jss1726 jss1731 jss1733">
        <div theme="[object Object]" class="jss2740" style="position: relative; border: none; box-shadow: none; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; background: none;">
          <div class="jss1039" title=""><span class="jss1049"><span class="jss1050 jss1037 jss1054"></span></span>
          </div>
          <div class="jss1056 jss2740" theme="[object Object]"><img alt="SJ" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/gather-app/image/upload/c_limit,f_auto,q_auto,w_80/v1/qa/user_provided/user_profile/300/x5rkmkjoameevlj5zmof" class="jss1058"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="jss1745 jss2739"><span class="jss133 jss142 jss1748">Sally Jesse Jesse Rafael</span>
          <p class="jss133 jss141 jss166 jss1749">Invited by Aaron Aaronson</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="jss2846"><button class="jss906 jss1028" tabindex="0" type="button" aria-label="More" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="card-options-menu"><span class="jss1033"><svg class="jss169 jss170" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation"><path d="M12 8c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2s-.9-2-2-2-2 .9-2 2 .9 2 2 2zm0 2c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2s.9 2 2 2 2-.9 2-2-.9-2-2-2zm0 6c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2s.9 2 2 2 2-.9 2-2-.9-2-2-2z"></path></svg></span><span class="jss909"></span></button></div>
    </li>
    <li class="jss1724">
      <div class="jss1723 jss1726 jss1731 jss1733">
        <div theme="[object Object]" class="jss2740" style="position: relative; border: none; box-shadow: none; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; background: none;">
          <div class="jss1039" title=""><span class="jss1049"><span class="jss1050 jss1037 jss1054"></span></span>
          </div>
          <div class="jss1056 jss1057 jss2740" theme="[object Object]">SD</div>
        </div>
        <div class="jss1745 jss2739"><span class="jss133 jss142 jss1748">Super-Dave User</span>
          <p class="jss133 jss141 jss166 jss1749">Invited by Aaron Aaronson</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="jss2846"><button class="jss906 jss1028" tabindex="0" type="button" aria-label="More" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="card-options-menu"><span class="jss1033"><svg class="jss169 jss170" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation"><path d="M12 8c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2s-.9-2-2-2-2 .9-2 2 .9 2 2 2zm0 2c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2s.9 2 2 2 2-.9 2-2-.9-2-2-2zm0 6c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2s.9 2 2 2 2-.9 2-2-.9-2-2-2z"></path></svg></span><span class="jss909"></span></button></div>
    </li>
    <li class="jss1724">
      <div class="jss1723 jss1726 jss1731 jss1733">
        <div theme="[object Object]" class="jss2740" style="position: relative; border: none; box-shadow: none; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; background: none;">
          <div class="jss1039" title=""><span class="jss1049"><span class="jss1050 jss1037 jss1054"></span></span>
          </div>
          <div class="jss1056 jss1057 jss2740" theme="[object Object]">TF</div>
        </div>
        <div class="jss1745 jss2739"><span class="jss133 jss142 jss1748">Tester Fester</span>
          <p class="jss133 jss141 jss166 jss1749">Invited by Aaron Aaronson</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="jss2846"><button class="jss906 jss1028" tabindex="0" type="button" aria-label="More" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="card-options-menu"><span class="jss1033"><svg class="jss169 jss170" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation"><path d="M12 8c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2s-.9-2-2-2-2 .9-2 2 .9 2 2 2zm0 2c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2s.9 2 2 2 2-.9 2-2-.9-2-2-2zm0 6c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2s.9 2 2 2 2-.9 2-2-.9-2-2-2z"></path></svg></span><span class="jss909"></span></button></div>
    </li>
    <li class="jss1724">
      <div class="jss1723 jss1726 jss1731 jss1733">
        <div theme="[object Object]" class="jss2740" style="position: relative; border: none; box-shadow: none; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; background: none;">
          <div class="jss1039" title=""><span class="jss1049"><span class="jss1050 jss1037 jss1054"></span></span>
          </div>
          <div class="jss1056 jss1057 jss2740" theme="[object Object]">ZC</div>
        </div>
        <div class="jss1745 jss2739"><span class="jss133 jss142 jss1748">Zach Chatterton</span>
          <p class="jss133 jss141 jss166 jss1749">Invited by Aaron Aaronson</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="jss2846"><button class="jss906 jss1028" tabindex="0" type="button" aria-label="More" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="card-options-menu"><span class="jss1033"><svg class="jss169 jss170" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation"><path d="M12 8c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2s-.9-2-2-2-2 .9-2 2 .9 2 2 2zm0 2c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2s.9 2 2 2 2-.9 2-2-.9-2-2-2zm0 6c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2s.9 2 2 2 2-.9 2-2-.9-2-2-2z"></path></svg></span><span class="jss909"></span></button></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: I can't speak to why Selenium is being erratic, but strictly in terms of the correct xpath expression for the html snippet in your question, `//li/ul/li/div/button` or even `//li//div/button` should work.

Comment: OMG... thank you @JackFleeting!! This has been bugging me for a couple hours now.

I got it to work using the index of the items I wanted like:
```'//li[3]/ul/li[12]/div/button'``` 
I'm just curious as to why the copied xpath from Chrome didn't work here (it works most everywhere else)?

Comment: I honestly would rather find these items by something more unique, in case the order of index changes. Should I be able to check for attributes of the elements using the approach mentioned above (i.e. get_attribute()?)

Comment: The long, absolute xpath expressions copied from the developer tab only work on the document as it is **at that moment**. As you mentioned, things, like index positions, change constantly. That's the reason why short, relative, xpath expressions pointing directly to the target element work better; these tend to change much less frequently.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. I may need to refactor quite a few of these expressions then... I like the conciseness of the shorter, relative paths and the ability to back out an element or so and check that the attributes (mainly text) match those of my test case. Seriously, thanks for helping me get un-stumped!